# Is my UINavigationController still animating?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a series of pushViewController and popViewController actions,
e.g. I want to pop the topmost controller and push two other controllers one on top of the other and you I it all animated:

how can I ask the navigationController if it is still animating ? to prevent two animations from happening at the same time ?

what will be the values returned by the viewControllers and visibleViewController during the time the animation of a push or pop is still running?

Eyal

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can identify the animation status.

You can do the pop and the first push with `animated` set to `NO` and the last one set to `YES`. Or you can consider using [`setViewControllers:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers%3aanimated%3a) too.

Otherwise if you really want to be informed about pushing and popping, you can look at the delegate methods. Especially the [`navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController%3adidShowViewController%3aanimated%3a) method.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak,
I am not sure I can do the first because when doing the first push I don't necessarily know if a second one will follow. I will look into the delegate methods and see if they can help.